# android database problem

Tags: android, database

I have a problem with the database. I have a 9 databases which I need to use this 9 databases dynamically in the application...how can I do this....

Can I use the Hibernates for this problem. If yes how can I use it?

Comment: i am curious to know the need for 9 databases on a mobile app , are you porting enterprise software or a payroll application to mobile ?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate doesn't support Android (as far as I know).

If you want to have multiple databases open, try my post which shows how to have two databases open. [Android multiple databases open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498664/android-multiple-databases-open/4499816#4499816)

You can easily extend the solution to support your 9 databases.

Answer (score 1):

Are these SQLite databases (this is the Android 'default')?

Then you can use the Android libraries directly and just use 9 connection objects.