# Android: SQLite using wrong database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm using multiple SQLite databases in my android java project. The first one (for a login) works fine, using the following code and I am closing the connection. However, on the following page i'm calling a function which uses a different database but it seems to still reference the first database and not the new one. I'm getting this error:

```
09-14 13:18:01.990: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(10035): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table:
 NextID, db=/mnt/extSdCard/DirectEnquiries/AuditingData/Static/Users
```

Which is right, NextID isn't in Users.

Here is the code for the login page which uses the Users table:

```
if(String.valueOf(loginCount).equals("2")) {

        File dbfile = new File(Global.StaticDB + "/Users" ); 
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT UserID from Users where UserID like '" + txtUsername.getText().toString().trim() + "' AND Password like '" + txtPassword.getText().toString().trim() + "'", null); 
        c.moveToFirst();

        if(c.getCount() > 0) {
            Global.Username = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("UserID"));
            Global.currentDB = spnLocation.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Global.currentDBfull = Global.sctArea + Global.currentDB;

            db.close();
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Logged In";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            Intent ShowMainPage = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainPage.class);
            startActivityForResult(ShowMainPage, 0);


        }
```

The next page is using this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setText(Global.Username);
    TextView dbtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDB);
    dbtxt.setText(Functions.getNextID("StationObjects"));

}
```

And the function is:

```
public static int getNextID(String tablename) {
    Log.e("Current DB is: ", Global.currentDBfull);
    File dbfile = new File(Global.currentDBfull); 
    SQLiteDatabase dbF = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);

    int rtnID=(int)DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(dbF,"Select NxtNumber from NextID where NxtTable like '" + tablename + "'",null);    
    rtnID += 1;
    //db.rawQuery("update NextID set NxtNumber = '" + rtnID + "' where NxtTable like 'StationObjects'", null);
    dbF.close();
    return rtnID;
}
```

How do I make sure it uses the second database and not the first?
Tom

Comment: Where did you close your cursor on that login Database?

Comment: Just tried closing the cursor on the first sub but still the same error

Comment: You didn't post many of your logcat. Can we just check the "Current DB is:" message, exceptions and so on ? Also what is Global.sctArea, and what happens if (c.getCount() > 0) is false ? You're hidding many informations (I know that's for simplicity, but it's not helping much...)

Comment: Are you sure Global.currentDBfull points to the right path? Use static variables very carefully. Have you tried to  user raw query insread of DatabaseUtils.longForQuery?

Comment: can u put the whole log post.. its insufficient data

Comment: Check this thread regarding multiple databases in android [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498664/android-multiple-databases-open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the following format to open and close your database:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases/DATABASE_NAME.db";
private static SQLiteDatabase db;
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
// RUN YOUR QUERIES ETC
db.close()
```

For the case of 2 databases you would need to define 2 DB_PATHs and reference them where relevent.

Hope this helps,
L & L Partners