# Android Detach Database

Tags: android, sqlite, detach

I use in my application 2 databases. I have a main database which is used the most and at some point I need the 2nd database. So, in order to use it I attached it to the main database using this method:

```
public void attachDb(String dbName, String dbAlias){
    String dbPath = context.getDatabasePath(dbName).getAbsolutePath();
    myDataBase.execSQL("attach database '" + dbPath + "' as " + dbAlias);
}
```

Now my problem is that I want to detach the 2nd database when I exit the screen and I get a Force Close. I tried to detach it using this code:

```
 public void detachDatabase(String dbName){
    String dbPath = context.getDatabasePath(dbName).getAbsolutePath();
    myDataBase.execSQL("detach database '" + dbPath + "'");
}
```

The error log says this:

```
05-13 11:48:23.173: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7338): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-145
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: error code 1: SQL logic error or missing database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:92)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1899)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1839)
        at com.example.DBManagerBase.detachDatabase(DBManagerBase.java:168)
        at com.example.run(MyClass.java:233)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: Don't attach and detach the databases, use one adapter that keeps multiple databases. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498664/android-multiple-databases-open

Comment: And if I make query which joins tables from both databases will that example work? In my humble opinion I don't think if it work if they are not attached.

Comment: Joins only work in tables that are in the same database context. You cannot in any case join two tables that are in separate databases with SQL. You'd need to do selects from each of the tables and do the join on the resulting data in your code.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek Joining tables from `ATTACH`ed databases works just fine.

Comment: @ziziana Please show the entire error log.

Comment: @CL, I've updated my post with the entire log.

Comment: Are you aware that this error happens not in `detachDatabase` but in `attachDatabase`?

Comment: I updated the post again, but the error is the same. Instead of attached is now detached. Before I managed to attach the database but now it seems it doesn't work anymore. And I don't know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

use only myDataBase.execSQL("detach " + dbAlias)
You don't use the database's path+name, just the alias you gave.