# Communicate between two SQLite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing one application,my application contains two databases.**First database has only master tables and second table has only transactional tables**.Is there any changes to communicate between two SQLite databases.Please give some suggestions and tutorial.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer on similar topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498664/android-multiple-databases-open

Comment: [ATTACH DATABASE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest one database with both tables, however if there are constraints that are required for that design, then you would have to make content providers to handle both databases if it's in one application or if you have to share the data across applications, then each application should have a content provider.  Both content providers should be set android:exported="true" in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I think the process would  the same. You need to do the same as you do for the first . Like make a connection, open Database , execute query and so on. There might be some difficult with implementing joins and all that