# Connecting to a single database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have 2 classes which connect to a database. But with my current implementation I have to connect to 2 different databases.How can I fix this? If I use the same name for both databases it gives me an error

One class.....

```
 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "140398L.db";
    Context context;
    public PersistantAccountDAO(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Other class......

```
 public class PersistantTransactionDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements TransactionDAO {
     public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "140398L";
     public PersistantTransactionDAO(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
     }
```

Comment: `it gives me an error` **WHICH** error?

Comment: Please show where these classes derive from. Do you use ``SqliteOpenHelper``? Most convenient way in android to deal with sqlite. And use only one instance of it. Run your queries through this one instance.

Comment: share error you are getting also refer to this url for accessing 2 databases at same time  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498664/android-multiple-databases-open

Answer (score 0):

The `DatabaseName` is different, one class is `140398L.db` and the other is `140398L`