# How to access and connect two SQLite data bases in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I have 2 SQLite databases in my android project, 1 is used to store profile details of users and another one stores book appointments. Currently the two do not link but work fine. I might sound a bit stupid, but is it possible to connect the two so when some clicks on the booked appointment of a certain user it will go to their profile. I cannot see a way how this can be possible and after spending quite a well I've not been proven right.

If it is possible, could I please get some pointers as how to go about doing it. I have unique id's in both that increment, and potentially the names would be same in both but I have no measures to check for links etc.

Sorry if I have not made myself clear, I am quite loss with this and having spent several days, the only way I can think of doing it is redesigning the whole thing and instead of having seperate databases, have one for both but only shoot off relevant content to the activities required i.e. profile details to one and appointments to another. Not sure whether this will work as well and I have already spent very long designing what I have!

Comment: Did you just create 2 databases? If yes please consider using single a database.

Comment: Check this out:
[Multiple databases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4499816/1636478)

Comment: @Enzokie I created 2 separate databases with 2 tables... I hoped I hadn't took extra effort when not necessary.

Comment: @maatik5, it would be a lot of work for to get there I assume. I might just have to scrap that idea all together and maybe when I redesign I'll use that.

Comment: @AdamBrown I am afraid that you need to scrap everything and build a single database. If entities are related separating it with another database will not give you any advantage but another headache.

Answer (score 0):

I I suggest to export table(s) from one database to another one. it is easy and compared to what you are trying to do, is like a piece of cake. you can do [this](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/664327/copy-table-schema-and-data-from-one-database-to-an) in SQL Server(i assumed it is your database) without have to code. but i stand correct if you need some of your data, you must do it with queries.

Comment: Sounds easy when writing, I am sure there's a lot more to it then what's been said. I don't think how you described it it'll solve my problem unless I am missing the link. What I really is provide user the privilege to go to 2nd database from previous and view, update and delete information. Nonetheless, I was quite interested to read about the export... you mentioned, though it doesn't solve my problem I can use that for something. Would you happen to know how to export and import sqlite database tables?

Comment: didn't u see the link? this blue in text above?
https://www.codeproject.com/tips/664327/copy-table-schema-and-data-from-one-database-to-an