# SQLite - Cross Database Query not working

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I want to execute cross-database query in SQLite in Android. I have two tables in two different databases.

```
attach database 'data/data/com.app/databases/db1' as db1; 
attach database 'data/data/com.app/databases/db2' as db2; 
SELECT db1.tbl1.* FROM db1.tbl1 JOIN db2.tbl2 ON db1.tbl1.primaryKey = db2.tbl2.primaryKey 
WHERE db1.tbl1.columnX = ?  AND db2.tbl2.columnY  = ?
```

By calling this query with Android rawQuery method like :

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{"1","xyz"});
```

I am getting this error:

```
SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0xa6259ec8
```

I checked the syntax of query and it is correct.
Is it not possible to execute cross-database query in Android?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4499816/3364266

Comment: @SamirBhatt Yes Opening multiple databases works fine, but querying data is not working.

Comment: same db file : attach database 'data/data/com.app/databases/db1' as db1; 
attach database 'data/data/com.app/databases/db1' as db2;

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Sorry it was my typo. Corrected

Answer (score 0):

> I checked the syntax of query and it is correct. Is it not possible to
>   execute cross-database query in Android?

Yes it is possible as the example included demonstrates.

I think that your issue is that you appear to be using the incorrect `rawQuery` method/signature.

instead of :-

```
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, "1","xyz");
```

I believe that you should be using :-

```
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{"1","xyz"});
```

The former only supplying the 1 bind item as opposed to the two expected bind items (*although what you are using doesn't even appear to be a valid signature for rawQuery*)

However, I do suspect, from testing that you have additional issues with regard to the query. Here is a working example based upon your original post (i.e the attached databases are in fact the same databases, this shouldn't matter in principle though) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String DBNAME1 = "db1";
    public static final String DBNAME2 = "db2";
    public static final String DBNAME3 = "db3";
    public static final String ID_COLUMN = "_id";
    public static final String TABLENAME_BASE = "_table_main";
    public static final String NAMECOLUMN_BASE = "_name";
    public static final String DB2_COL_NAME = DBNAME2 + NAMECOLUMN_BASE;
    public static final String EXTENDED_DB2TABLENAME = DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE;
    public static final String EXTENDED_DB3TABLENAME = DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE;
    public static final String DB2_FULL_IDCOL = EXTENDED_DB2TABLENAME + "." + ID_COLUMN;
    public static final String DB2_FULL_NAMECOL = EXTENDED_DB2TABLENAME + "." + DBNAME2 + NAMECOLUMN_BASE;
    public static final String DB3_FULL_IDCOL = EXTENDED_DB3TABLENAME + "." + ID_COLUMN;
    public static final String DB3_FULL_NAMECOL = EXTENDED_DB3TABLENAME + "." + DBNAME2 + NAMECOLUMN_BASE;

    private static final String[] DB1NAMES = new String[] {"Fred","Bert","Harry","Tom","Dick"};
    private static final String[] DB2NAMES = new String[] {"Alan","George","Robert","Colin","Ian","John"};

    String mDB1Path, mDB2path;
    SQLiteDatabase mMaster;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDB1Path = createDatbase(DBNAME1);
        mDB2path = createDatbase(DBNAME2);

        /* Just to add some data for 1st run
        for (String s: DB2NAMES) {
            insertRow(DBNAME1,s);
        }
        for (String s: DB1NAMES) {
            insertRow(DBNAME2,s);
        }
        */

       // Open the main database and attach databases
        mMaster = this.openOrCreateDatabase(mDB1Path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        String attachsql = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + mDB2path + "' AS " + DBNAME2;
        String attachsql2 = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + mDB2path + "' AS " +  DBNAME3;
        mMaster.execSQL(attachsql);
        mMaster.execSQL(attachsql2);

        // Prepare first query between all 3 DB's
        String sqlstr = "SELECT " +
                DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE + ".*, " +
                DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + DB2_COL_NAME +
                ", " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + DB2_COL_NAME +
                " FROM " + DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " JOIN " + DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " ON " + DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " =  " + DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " JOIN " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " ON " + DBNAME1 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " =  " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN;

        // Write query string to log
        Log.d("SELECTSQL_1",sqlstr);
        // Perform the query an write resultant data to the log
        Cursor csr = mMaster.rawQuery(sqlstr,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String logdata = "Row = " + csr.getPosition();
            for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                logdata = logdata + " Column = " + csr.getColumnName(i) +
                        " Value = " + csr.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("CSRINFO",logdata);
        }

        // Arguments for 2nd query
        String arg1 = "12";
        String arg2 = "Fred";

        // SQL for 2nd query including WHERE clause
        String sqlstr2 = " SELECT " +
                DB2_FULL_IDCOL + ", " +
                DB2_FULL_NAMECOL + ", " +
                DB3_FULL_IDCOL + ", " +
                DB3_FULL_NAMECOL +
                " FROM " + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " JOIN " + DBNAME3 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE +
                " ON   " + DBNAME2 + "." + DBNAME2 + TABLENAME_BASE + "." + ID_COLUMN +
                " =    " + DB3_FULL_IDCOL +
                " WHERE " +
                DB3_FULL_IDCOL + "=? AND " +
                DB3_FULL_NAMECOL + "=?";

        // Log the query string
        Log.d("SELECTSQL_2",sqlstr2);
        // Perform 2nd query and log cursor result 
        Cursor csr2 = mMaster.rawQuery(sqlstr2,new String[]{arg1,arg2});
        while (csr2.moveToNext()) {
            String logdata = "Row = " + csr2.getPosition();
            for (int i=0; i < csr2.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                logdata = logdata + " Column = " + csr2.getColumnName(i) +
                        " Value = " + csr2.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("CSRINFO",logdata);
        }
    }

    // Used to create the two actual databases
    private String createDatbase(String dbqualifier) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(dbqualifier,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        String tblcrtstr = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                dbqualifier + TABLENAME_BASE +
                "(" +
                ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                dbqualifier + NAMECOLUMN_BASE  + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(tblcrtstr);
        String rv = db.getPath();
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }

    // Insert a row to the respective database
    private void insertRow(String dbqualifier, String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(dbqualifier,MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(dbqualifier + NAMECOLUMN_BASE, name);
        db.insert(dbqualifier + TABLENAME_BASE,null,cv);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

I believe that you are mainly interested in the 2nd query which is :-

```
SELECT db2.db2_table_main._id, db2.db2_table_main.db2_name, db3.db2_table_main._id, db3.db2_table_main.db2_name FROM db2_table_main JOIN db3.db2_table_main ON   db2.db2_table_main._id =    db3.db2_table_main._id WHERE db3.db2_table_main._id=? AND db3.db2_table_main.db2_name=?
```

*Note the above query is based upon the original post which had the same database attached twice.*

Running the above (after a number of runs that included the commented out row insertion code) produced the following results:-

From/for the first query :-

```
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/SELECTSQL_1: SELECT db1_table_main.*, db2.db2_table_main.db2_name, db3.db2_table_main.db2_name FROM db1_table_main JOIN db2.db2_table_main ON db1_table_main._id =  db2.db2_table_main._id JOIN db3.db2_table_main ON db1_table_main._id =  db3.db2_table_main._id
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 0 Column = _id Value = 1 Column = db1_name Value = Fred Column = db2_name Value = Alan Column = db2_name Value = Alan
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 1 Column = _id Value = 2 Column = db1_name Value = Bert Column = db2_name Value = George Column = db2_name Value = George
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 2 Column = _id Value = 3 Column = db1_name Value = Harry Column = db2_name Value = Robert Column = db2_name Value = Robert
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 3 Column = _id Value = 4 Column = db1_name Value = Tom Column = db2_name Value = Colin Column = db2_name Value = Colin
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 4 Column = _id Value = 5 Column = db1_name Value = Dick Column = db2_name Value = Ian Column = db2_name Value = Ian
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 5 Column = _id Value = 6 Column = db1_name Value = Alan Column = db2_name Value = John Column = db2_name Value = John
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 6 Column = _id Value = 7 Column = db1_name Value = George Column = db2_name Value = Fred Column = db2_name Value = Fred
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 7 Column = _id Value = 8 Column = db1_name Value = Robert Column = db2_name Value = Bert Column = db2_name Value = Bert
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 8 Column = _id Value = 9 Column = db1_name Value = Colin Column = db2_name Value = Harry Column = db2_name Value = Harry
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 9 Column = _id Value = 10 Column = db1_name Value = Ian Column = db2_name Value = Tom Column = db2_name Value = Tom
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 10 Column = _id Value = 11 Column = db1_name Value = John Column = db2_name Value = Dick Column = db2_name Value = Dick
11-05 07:37:52.764 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 11 Column = _id Value = 12 Column = db1_name Value = Alan Column = db2_name Value = Fred Column = db2_name Value = Fred
11-05 07:37:52.765 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 12 Column = _id Value = 13 Column = db1_name Value = George Column = db2_name Value = Bert Column = db2_name Value = Bert
11-05 07:37:52.765 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 13 Column = _id Value = 14 Column = db1_name Value = Robert Column = db2_name Value = Harry Column = db2_name Value = Harry
11-05 07:37:52.765 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 14 Column = _id Value = 15 Column = db1_name Value = Colin Column = db2_name Value = Tom Column = db2_name Value = Tom
11-05 07:37:52.765 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 15 Column = _id Value = 16 Column = db1_name Value = Ian Column = db2_name Value = Dick Column = db2_name Value = Dick
```

From the 2nd query with the WHERE clause:-

```
11-05 07:37:52.765 2726-2726/? D/SELECTSQL_2:  SELECT db2.db2_table_main._id, db2.db2_table_main.db2_name, db3.db2_table_main._id, db3.db2_table_main.db2_name FROM db2_table_main JOIN db3.db2_table_main ON   db2.db2_table_main._id =    db3.db2_table_main._id WHERE db3.db2_table_main._id=? AND db3.db2_table_main.db2_name=?
11-05 07:37:52.765 2726-2726/? D/CSRINFO: Row = 0 Column = _id Value = 12 Column = db2_name Value = Fred Column = _id Value = 12 Column = db2_name Value = Fred
```

I.e  it has selected just the one row from the 16 rows, i.e. the one row that has a **12** in the **_id** column and **Fred** in the **Name** column of the 2nd attached (db3) database.

Comment: It was a typo. can you help?